# Can I perform tayammum (dry ablution) instead of wudu in the Canadian winter?

Tags: wudu, tayammum

I live in Canada, where in the winter, you can't remove your several layers of clothing to expose your hands and feet to make wudu, even if water is available. Can I perform [Tayammum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tayammum) (dry ablution) in such case?

In winter the grounds are covered by thick layer of ice, and soil is not available.

Comment: I understand you would get very cold if you did it outdoors, but why can't you do wudu indoors?

Comment: You say there's no soil available (because of the ice layer covering it) so how would you perform tayammum? Tayammum needs a soil that is purefied by the sun...

Comment: If you are visiting some place for a short period, exposing the hands by removing your clothes for Wudu may not be an option. Additionally there is no facility for Wudu, unless spilling water all over the basin counter.

Comment: Soil can be stored & carried around in a small amount

Comment: I know that it can be, but don't know the rulings of madhabs who insist of soil only for tayammum.

Answer (score 2):

Allah says in ([5:6](http://legacy.quran.com/5/6)):

> ... And if you are in a state of janabah, then purify yourselves. But if you are ill **or** on a journey **or** one of you comes from the place of relieving himself **or** you have contacted women **and** do not find water, then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and hands with it. Allah does not intend to make difficulty for you, but He intends to purify you and complete His favor upon you that you may be grateful.

So the verse clearly say that a major condition for the permission of tayammum is the need or the absence of water.

On the other Allah also says that we should neither harm nor kill ourselves:

> And spend in the way of Allah and do not throw [yourselves] with your [own] hands into destruction [by refraining]. And do good; indeed, Allah loves the doers of good. ([2:195](http://legacy.quran.com/2/195))
>
> ... And do not kill yourselves [or one another]. Indeed, Allah is to you ever Merciful. ([4:29)](http://legacy.quran.com/4/29)

And HE says that we are allowed to do something prohibited in case of necessity (under some conditions which explain the necessity):

> And why should you not eat of that upon which the name of Allah has been mentioned while **He has explained in detail to you what He has forbidden you, excepting that to which you are compelled**.  ... ([6:119](http://legacy.quran.com/6/119))

This means if you have water you should use it unless using it would make you sick or may harm you. But you must be aware that you'll have the option to use warm or hot water for wudu' and ghusl! If you reject it for no good reason at least you would commit a sin.

So far the legal basis for you to make your decision!

Here's a fatwa on the topic [islamqa #70507](https://islamqa.info/en/70507).